# Can't customize inflection (ID)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zeitwerk

The controller:

```
# app/controllers/v1/nem_id_controller.rb
class V1::NemIDController < ApplicationController
end
```

I created an initializer to customize the inflection:

```
# config/initializers/zeitwerk.rb
Rails.autoloaders.each do |autoloader|
  autoloader.inflector = Zeitwerk::Inflector.new
  autoloader.inflector.inflect(
    "nem_id" => "NemID"
  )
end
```

The error:

```
expected file app/controllers/v1/nem_id_controller.rb to define constant V1::NemIdController
```

Inspired from:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#customizing-inflections

It does not work with inflection.acronym('ID') because it will cause this error: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40068

Comment: You will need to define the full thing, "nem_id_controller" => "NemIDController"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overrides for `Zeitwerk::Inflector` are simpler than you're thinking. From the [fine source code](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk/blob/v2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/inflector.rb#L15):

```
def camelize(basename, _abspath)
  overrides[basename] || basename.split('_').each(&:capitalize!).join
end
```

The overrides are applied to whole components (i.e. `nem_id_controller`) or underscore-delimited components (i.d. `nem`, `id`, `controller`). You want to override the whole `nem_id_controller`:

```
autoloader.inflector.inflect(
  'nem_id_controller' => 'NemIDController'
)
```

Answer (score 3):

From the official guide

```rb
# config/initializers/zeitwerk.rb
Rails.autoloaders.each do |autoloader|
  autoloader.inflector = Zeitwerk::Inflector.new
  autoloader.inflector.inflect(
    "html_parser" => "HTMLParser",
    "ssl_error"   => "SSLError"
  )
end
```

If you want a common acronym to be recognized as such across all constants. You can set it as such:

```rb
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym "CSV"
end
```

but Be careful, after you do this, you can't have mixed constants such as

CsvData and CSVPage

Pick your preference or otherwise, with the autoloader inflector, you can define both separately.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#customizing-inflections